# How to manage huge number of records using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, trigger.io

I have 20K records in Excel on S3. My design looks like below to process these records.
SQSWriterLambda -> SQS -> SQSReaderLambda -> Server.
SQSWriterLambda would read excel file and send messages to SQS, 1 message for each record in excel so there will be 20k sqs messages. SQSReaderLambda would get triggered based on messages receiving in SQS. It will send content of message to final server for processing. But my server can process only 5k messages in 24 hours. So I am looking for a solution of handling remaining 15k records somehow. I am going to put excel sheet once on S3 and I want lambda to process records(5k per 24 hours) within any number of days.

Visibility timeout has 12 hours as max value. My 1st lambda can put 20k messages on sqs. But 2nd lambda would fail after processing 5k records.

Comment: Why your server doesn't process the sqs by itself? If it had, you could setup autoscaling group to scale your server instances (I assume ec2 instnaces) based on SQS queue.

Comment: Server service is from Government side API. I am calling that API from my lambda. I am not using EC2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure what is the problem if you can't make the server to process >5K of messages a day. The problem is how to send 5K of messages per day using lambda?

Comment: I am sending 5k records through SQS to my 2nd lambda. The API call is very fast. So my 2nd lambda processes all 5k records within 15 minutes. But I am not sure how to handle those remaining 15k records. Server API has throttling limit of 5k records per 24 hours. Later it starts sending error.

Comment: I made answer as what I wanted to write is too long and annoying without formation in comments.

Comment: When you say "process only 5k messages in 24 hours", is it allowed to process 5k messages in the first hour (and then wait 23 hours), or does it need to spread those messages over the full day (eg 4 per minute)?

Comment: If you have the max visibility timeout at 12 hours, won't that just mean the first 5000 succeed, the rest fail (if the batch size is set correctly), the rest get put back on the queue, where they will be invisible for 12 hours and then the lambda tries to process them again (and will fail again because 24 hours aren't up yet), then they're invisible for 12 hours again THEN the lambda can process another 5000...and so on. Would all be done in ~ 4 days?

Answer (score 0):

If you hooked up lambda to sqs it will try to submit all 20K messages to the second lambda for processing. I think decoupling SQS with  the second lambda should work.

You could consider the following approach:

1. Replace second lambda function with a "free-standing one" (not connected to SQS). The second function instead would itself query the SQS in an iterative manner. It would just query 5K of messages from it.
2. Setup CloudWatch Events rule to automatically trigger your function once a day. This way you would just process 5K messages per day.

Note that default retention limit of a message in SQS is 4 days which is just enough for 20K of messages (5K x 4 days). But you can increase it up to 14 days if needed.

Comment: In my earlier solution, 2nd Lambda was connected to SQS. So for each sqs message, new instance of Lambda was getting initiated. As per your suggestion, If I remove SQS and Lambda binding and take SQS messages manually, then my 2nd Lambda might timed out. I dont think it can process all 5000 records within 15 minutes with retry logic implemented.(Lambda's max timeout)